# Angular confitional ngIf to hide a child component

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a child component being called based on the boolean returned from `showSidebar()`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showSidebar()">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</ng-container>
```

If `showSidebar()` is false, the `app-sidebar` component is not displayed, but the methods in it's typescript class are still being called. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on just from this bit of template. Could you share the showSidebar() method as well? Is it possible that it evaluates to true before false (causing the app-sidebar component to init)?

Comment: `showSidebar()` is a method, you are calling this method which should ideally return boolean value so that template engine can hide or show the component. It will be called multiple times irrespective* of display state.

Answer (score 1):

When you use any method in structural directive angular will call that method every time change detection happens to check if value that method returning is changed or not. You can use variable instead and update value of variable as per your requirements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).